# Show or Hide One or More controls based on Checked checkboxList Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Sorry experts but I have spent half of today googling this but could find any helpful solutions.

I have a checkboxList control with ID called ckRequestReview. This checkboxList control has three items.

Our requirement is that if a  user clicks one of those items, display two textboxes associated with it.

If user checks all three checkbox items, display all six textbox controls.

So far, only three are working.

Here is what needs to happen:

On page load, by default all six textbox controls are hidden.

User checks the **Job Title** checkbox item, two controls, **txtTitleChange** and **txtTitle** controls are made visible.

OR User checks the **Pay Range** checkbox item and two controls, **txtPayGradeChange** and **txtPayGrade** are made visible

OR User checks the **Class** checkbox item and two controls, **txtClassSpecChange** and **txtClassification**

OR User checks all three checkbox items and all six textbox controls are made visible.

So far, only these three textbox controls out of the six listed work correctly:

HTML

```
<div class="input text" style="float: left;">
    <span style="text-align: left; font-size: x-large; float: left;">Requested Change:</span>
    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitleChange" runat="server" placeholder="Job Title" Style="margin-right: 0px; width: 200px; display: none;" />&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayGradeChange" runat="server" placeholder="for Pay Range" Style="margin-right: 0px; width: 200px; display: none;" />&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClassSpecChange" runat="server" placeholder="for Class" Style="margin-right: 0px; width: 200px; display: none;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The other three do nothing when checkbox is either checked or unchecked.Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHide(chk, txt) {
        //Get the Textbox based on selected checkbox
        ctrltxt = document.getElementById(txt);
        //Check if checkbox is checked or not
        if (chk.checked) {
            //Show the Textbox
            ctrltxt.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            //Hide the textbox
            ctrltxt.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table style="border: 0; border-style: solid">
    <tr valign="top" style="background-color: #f5f7f7; font-size: large; white-space: nowrap;">
        <td style="font-size: large; font-weight: bold;">Request a Review of:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ckRequestReview" runat="server" CssClass="cb" Style="border-width: 0;" RepeatDirection="horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatLayout="Table">
                <asp:ListItem onclick="ShowHide(this,'txtTitleChange','txtTitle');"> Job Title</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem onclick="ShowHide(this,'txtPayGradeChange','txtPayGrade');">Pay Range</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem onclick="ShowHide(this,'txtClassSpecChange','txtClassification');">Class</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td valign="middle" style="font-size: large; font-weight: bold; border-top: thin solid; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap" class="style4">
            <br />
            <div class="input text" style="float: left;">
                <span style="text-align: left; font-size: x-large; float: left;">Requested Change:</span>
                <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitleChange" runat="server" placeholder="Job Title" Style="margin-right: 0px; width: 200px; display: none;" />&nbsp;
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayGradeChange" runat="server" placeholder="for Pay Range" Style="margin-right: 0px; width: 200px; display: none;" />&nbsp;
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClassSpecChange" runat="server" placeholder="for Class" Style="margin-right: 0px; width: 200px; display: none;" />
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="border:0;border-style:solid">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span style="font-size: X-large; text-align: left;">JUSTIFICATION</span>
            <br />
            <div class="input textarea">
                <table style="border:0;border-style:solid">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: large;" class="style22">
                            <asp:Label ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Text="Job Title" Style="width: 200px;" Font-Bold="False"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitleComments" runat="server" placeholder="Title Change Justification" Style="width: 400px;height:100px;" Font-Bold="False" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: large;" class="style21">
                            <asp:Label ID="txtPayGrade" runat="server" Text="Pay Range" Style="width: 200px;" Font-Bold="False"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayComments" placeholder="Pay Grade Change Justification" runat="server" Style="width: 400px;height:100px;" Font-Bold="False" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="border:0;border-style:solid">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: large;" class="style22">
                            <asp:Label ID="txtClassification" runat="server" Text="Class" Style="width: 200px;" Font-Bold="False"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtClassComments" placeholder="Class Specification Change Justification" runat="server" Style="width: 400px;height:100px;" Font-Bold="False" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correctly passing three parms to your JS, but are only handling 2. Replace it with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHide(chk, txt,txt2) {
        //Get the Textbox based on selected checkbox
        ctrltxt = document.getElementById(txt);
        ctrltxt2= document.getElementById(txt2);
        //Check if checkbox is checked or not
        if (chk.checked) {
           //Show the Textbox
           ctrltxt.style.display = 'block';
           ctrltxt2.style.display = 'block';
         } else {
           //Hide the textbox
           ctrltxt.style.display = 'none';
           ctrltxt2.style.display = 'none';
         }
     }
```

Comment: great work.

That was what I missing. Now, I works correctly.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: stackoverflow has helped me so often, I'm glad I could return the favor. :)